# JavaScript: Is the `if / else` statement faster than the conditional statement in?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, conditional-statements, micro-optimization

Consider the following two pieces of code:

```
var adj=0>grip.y?0<grip.x?0:-180:0<grip.x?-360:-180;
```

and

```
var adj;    
if (grip.y < 0) {   
    if (grip.x > 0)
        adj = 0;
    else
        adj = -180;
}
else {      
    if (grip.x > 0)
        adj = -360;
    else
        adj = -180;
}
```

They both produce the same result, but which is faster?

Comment: Micro-optimalisation, don't bother. If you care, create a benchmark on http://jsperf.com/

Comment: there will be little to none difference, use the more readable one.

Comment: Your first conditional is called the "ternary" operator.

Comment: They are both implemented as a branch if condition is true. No difference in performance. But only one is easier to read. Guess which one?

Comment: The second one is more maintainable, which should be the priority. Also consider using constants instead of hard-coding numeric values such as `-360`. For example, `var CIRCLE_DEGREES = 360`.

Comment: Why use the constants in this case?

Comment: in case for some reason you switch to radians, just do a 'rename', then change value, and all is ok...

Comment: Based on the idea to create a benchmark, I did on jsperf.com. http://jsperf.com/if-vs-conditional/2. And indeed, the results are negligible (at least in my case), but what's more interesting is that they differ based on the browser one is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed difference will be negligible - use whichever you find is more convinient and readable. There wont be any problem with the wrong conditional construct.

Comment: I know there's little difference between the too, but I'm interested in optimizing a `mousemove` event handler, so the less operations, the better (obviously).

Comment: @AndreiOniga I really think that there will be any such difference. It all depends on your convinience. Plz go through this link http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html. I would recommend if else or ternary operator as per your convinience. There are some examples(at the end) also in the link which may answer you. :)

Comment: I will confess that in many situations I prefer to use if...else simply for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch conditions,that is faster than if and other conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just to check the performance in JavaScript, I tried to do a small experiment.

```
console.time("ternary operator");
const val = (5 > 2) ? true : false;
console.timeEnd("ternary operator");

console.time("if condition");
let val2;
if (5 > 2) {
val2 = true;
} else {
val2 = false;
}
console.timeEnd("if condition");
```

and the output is quite shocking as the `if` condition is almost twice faster than the ternary statements.

Results :-
[image]

So to conclude I would suggest using the `if` condition over the ternary operator.

Ok so here is multiple tries of similar operation

[image]

Comment: You're also timing the printing which is *vastly* more expensive, especially than a constant condition which should optimize away during JIT.  The 2nd call to `console.log` is probably a lot faster after the first one warms it up.  (And the CPU has a chance to ramp up to max turbo, if it's a Skylake or later that can react in that amount of time.)  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) covers that - try reversing the order of these two things and see if it's always the 2nd one that's faster.

Comment: You need a more sophisticated test if you want to get meaningful results.  Like with [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809) where the condition isn't constant.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well looks like you are correct, I usually don't go on hypothesis like CPU is in that condition or this condition, I try to run the program multiple times (one after another) and observe the output data and take an average of it but looks like this time when I tried to run both of the programs separately to avoid any collision between both of their process, I found both of the data is almost similar.

Thank you for making me look into this one more time and this broke one of my conceptions that `if` condition is faster than ternary operators.
Thank you

Comment: Taking an average is good  (or discarding outliers and taking the best repeatable time for each version).  But yeah, if your methodology is flawed then you're just repeating the same mistake. Microbenchmarking is *hard*.  It's only simple for thing that run long enough to hide measurement / warm-up overhead, and even then it's possible to not be measuring what you thought you were, or to over-generalize results (e.g. throughput and latency are different things; some ways of benchmarking will depend on one or the other.)

Comment: @PeterCordes ya you are correct that I was logging console.log as well, however when I tried to remove it and run the similar code in console log on a Macbook pro here are the results.

and here are the results

Try 1
ternary operator: 0.006103515625 ms
if condition: 0.006103515625 ms

Try 2
ternary operator: 0.00830078125 ms
if condition: 0.00390625 ms

Try 3
ternary operator: 0.00830078125 ms
if condition: 0.006103515625 ms


Try 4
ternary operator: 0.0107421875 ms
if condition: 0.0068359375 ms

I see we have a clear winner of if/else case over ternary, except of Try 1.